# Кодирование - Декодирование

Tags: c#, кодировка

Надо проделать такую цепочку: Открыть файл (ANSI) -> Закодировать в UTF8+UrlEncode -> Раскодировать -> Сохранить (ANSI). Это подготовка для отправки файла через HTTP. Вот код:

```
          string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Souce");
          UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
          var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data));

          Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);  
          System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Finish", true, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
          writer.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ANSI.GetString(bytes)));
          writer.Close();
```

Но вместо некоторых символов стоят вопросительные знаки. Конечный файл весит на процент другой меньше. Где косяк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpUtility.UrlEncode по умолчанию использует UTF-8. Поэтому текст скорее всего проходит через всю эту мясорубку нетронутым до самого writer.WriteLine. По сути ваш код эквивалентен следующей строке:

```
File.WriteAllLines("Finish", File.ReadAllLines("Source"), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Запись в файл в кодировке 1251 просто заменяет все символы, которых нет в этой кодировке, на вопросы или на соответствующие символы из 1251. Т.е. все 2-3-4-байтовые последовательности из входного файла - русские буквы, например - урезаются до одного байта. Поэтому ваш файл худеет после конвертации.

Comment: И как сделать так, чтобы русские буквы не урезались, раз исходный файл именно в этой кодировке  ?

Comment: а что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать этой хитрой конвертацией? можете точно сказать, какие символы теряются?

Comment: Все русские буквы и теряются. Мне нужно отправить POST запросом файл, а без UriEncode отправка стопорится из-за символа '&'.

Comment: Если у вас POST-запрос, то файл надо отправлять в теле запроса, с `content-type=multipart/form-data`. В гугле куча примеров. Если очень надо отправить именно как параметр - то достаточно прогнать текст через [Uri.EscapeDataString(data)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Не получилось разобраться с multipart/form-data. С параметром проще. Мне нужно преобразовать файл в массив байтов. А Uri.EscapeDataString(data) возвращает строку. Так вот не работает: byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes("CookieVar=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(data) );

Comment: Значение параметра - это строка, а не массив байт. Зачем вы ее в byte[] преобразуете? Отправляйте резульат `Uri.EscapeDataString(data)`. А лучше разберитесь с `multipart/form-data`. И не пишите код наугад.

Comment: Хоть убейте - не получается. Перерыл все возможные примеры в гугле с отправкой файла при помощи multipart/form-data. На сервере никак не отображается тело запроса POST, эти нули показывают: $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA or php://stdin  (PHP)

Comment: даже [WebClient.UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) не работает? Может у вас на сервере проблема?

Comment: Вы шарите в PHP ? Значение $_FILES: array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "file.txt"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phplOqWCa"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}

Comment: Совсем нет. но если `WebClient.UploadFile` не помогает - значит проблема на сервере. содавайте отдельный вопрос :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало. Действительно, проблема была на сервере. Файл загружался, и его нужно было просто перенести - move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], PATH);